# "tapering" without the modifier or rotating

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image: Done by selecting faces and rotating]

I only want a single part of the mesh to be tapered without affecting the rest, other than using the modifier, how can I achieve this? Rotating achieves the effect however it slightly distorts the model, and doesn't work at extreme angles

Comment: Maybe scale it with the `S` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly you can use the shear tool for that. The shear tool can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.